# How to call method on a pointer to a C++ object using OpCodes.Calli

Tags: c#, c++, .net, il, sharpdx

When calling a method on a C++ object from .NET using the .calli IL-instruction, how do you resolve the pointer to the actual method you want to call? I realize that this is going to be platform dependant.

I know the excellent SharpDX library uses the .calli instruction extensively, and I have peeked at the code it generates, and the method pointer gets pulled out like this:

```
((void**)(*(void**)_nativePointer))[69]
```

where _nativePointer is a pointer to the object instance. It's then cast to a void** which is de-references, and then cast again to a void** which indexes into slot 69. I just can't figure out what exactly is going on here.

Comment: SharpDX is not exactly a good example, it makes calls to DirectX.  Which uses COM interfaces, you probably see it digging the function pointer out of the v-table.  Understanding how COM works is well beyond what could possibly fit in an SO answer.  Plenty of books about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Calli` opcode will only work with objects having a [vtable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) but cannot be used with standard C++ methods (non virtuals). It also requires that objects follow the same [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface), thus this is working well with COM as it defines a standard ABI to access C++ objects. But this will not work with, for example, C++ multiple inheritance.

In order to access plain C++ method on an object, you need to have a generated C wrapper that provides a plain C function for each C++ method where the first parameter is usually the instance of the C++ object and the following parameters are the parameters from the C++ method (Some wrapper, like CXXI, are sometimes able to link directly to C++ objects by following compilers ABI). So in order to make this bridge you can:

- Develop your own C wrapper (A dynamic library DLL/so that is providing these functions translating calls to C++ object)
- [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) is typically used to automate this kind of C++/C# bridge.
- There was also an attempt from some Mono folks to provide a C++ bridging called [CXXI](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2011/Dec-19.html), but doesn't seem to be developed.

Comment: Even though it was not the answer I wanted, this is the correct answer =(. Thanks!

Comment: How can 'calli' then be used to call the plain C function? How does one get the address to this? Would this be via 'LoadLibrary'/'GetProcAddress'?

Comment: `calli` allows to call any native function, the last parameter pushed to a calli instruction is the pointer of this function. For the method of a COM object, this pointer is coming from the vtable slot associated to this method. For an exported DLL function, that would be indeed the `LoadLibrary/GetProcessAddress`